# DB2 SQL Query to get the List of Employees whose Managers are changed in the past

Tags: sql

Can somone please help me with a DB2 SQL Query to get the List of Employees whose Managers are changed in the past ?

Sample Data (Same employee Table has ACTIVE and HISTORY Data)

```
EMP_ID EMP-FN  EMP-LN  MANAGER-ID  STATUS
1986   SMITH   JASON   2011        ACT
1986   ALLEN   WARD    2023        ACT
1986   CLARK   SCOTT   2038        ACT
1986   SMITH   JASON   2038        HIST
```

Result Expected

```
EMP_ID EMP-FN  EMP-LN  CURRENT-MANAGER-ID PRIOR-MANAGER-ID 
1986   SMITH   JASON   2011               2038
```

Thanks
CB

Comment: Your example data & expected result is quite confusing. Assuming the EMP_IDs are different for row 2&3: *self-join on emp_id*, `WHERE emp1.STATUS = 'ACT' AND emp2.STATUS = 'HIST'`. If there are multiple history rows you need more info about the order.

Comment: thank you. your assumption is correct. It worked for me.